# How to make datepicker opens to left when it is at the right edge of the page and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

The date range picker that I used only has options to either open to left or right. ([Bootstrap date picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)) If I set 'opens: left', when the datepicker is at the left edge of the page, it will skew to the bottom and its height will become really large.

Is there a way to write some JavaScript code to solve this kind of problem? Opens to left or right under different condition.

See image below: [image]

Comment: you haven't told us which datepicker it is, or shown us what code you used. We need one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve otherwise we've no idea what might be causing the problem

Comment: saying "it's similar to" and then posting a link to a datepicker. Are you using that one you linked to? Or did you literally mean you're using one that's a bit like it? Please clarify, or link to the real plugin if necessary